# How to hide form and show progress bar while submitting form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have looked at a few similar examples on StackOverflow but I can't seem to get this to work. I have an onclick event that goes to one function and if that returns ok it goes to another function and if that is fine it will submit it in the else statement like:

```
document.forms["input"].submit();
```

so I tried commenting this out and sending it to a function called showHide()

```
function showHide() {
    $('#input').submit(function () {
        $('#main-content').hide();
        $('#progress').show();
    });
}
```

It doesn't seem to submit the form like expected. I basically want to use bootstrap and show an animated progress bar so the user knows something is happening because sometimes the submission can take awhile.

**Update:**

I was able to get this working with both bootstrap progress bars and the jquery ui progress bar. I just run the progress bars right before it submits the form. I hide the div when i load the view.

```
        $(function() {

            $("#progress").show();
            });

        document.forms["input"].submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing more HTML, it's a bit hard to troubleshoot. But it looks like you've defined a function, and within this function you're expecting an element to trigger it, which won't really work. You could call your function from your form's submit event, like so:

```
//this assumes you have a form with id "input"
$('#input').submit(function () {
    showHide();
});
function showHide() {
    $('#main-content').hide();
    $('#progress').show();      
}
```

Simple [JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KLkVE/)

Comment: I'm not sure how I could implement this exactly. I submit on my else statement is this possible with jquery? For instance, if it gets to my else statement then it will submit the form.

Comment: You didn't mention any other logic in your question, so I purposely left that out. If you have conditional logic in your function (form field validation, for example), simply `return true;` when all is good, otherwise `return false;` to prevent the form from submitting.

Answer (score 0):

`document.forms` is an object containing the **names** of forms not the **IDs**.

If your form doesn't have a **name** of input (`<form name="input">...</form>`), the jQuery selector you're binding to won't work. Instead you'll need to use `$('[name=input']).submit(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

form submit reloads page.

hence in your head section add:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  // Animate loader off screen
  console.log("loading");
  $("#dvLoading").fadeOut(2000);
});
```